# Run bash script every 10 minutes in PM2

Tags: node.js, cron, pm2

How can I run PM2 with bash/php/etc scripts using [`cron_restart`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/#control-flow) attribute?

The problem is the script restarts at the moment it finishes, rather than waiting for the next trigger time.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >> time.log
sleep 5
```

Configuration:

```
{
    "apps" : [
        {
            "name": "worker",
            "cwd": "/home/dmitry/test",
            "script": "./time.sh",
            "cron_restart": "* * * * *",
            "exec_interpreter": "bash"
        }
    ]
}
```

The script has `sleep 5`, so it's executed 12 times per minute instead of 1 (crontab pattern `* * * * *`). It looks like `cron_restart` is broken.

**Updated**:

It works with `"exec_interpreter": "node"` for javascript files. But I want to run bash and php.

Comment: Hey, your script is running fine with `"exec_interpreter": "bash"`. What exactly the problem you are facing ? Here, is the tail time.log file 
[mohan@centos-workstation]$ tail -f time.log 
Tue Apr 17 16:15:12 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:17 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:22 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:27 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:32 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:37 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:42 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:47 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:52 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:15:57 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:16:02 UTC 2018
Tue Apr 17 16:16:07 UTC 2018

Comment: It should be launched every 2 minutes, not every 5 seconds. With js file it works as planned.